# How to set custom variables through the new analytics.js of GA

Tags: google-analytics

See the Guide https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets

I cant find any way to track Custom Variables like the old tracking js "ga.js": https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables

```
_setCustomVar(index, name, value, opt_scope)
```

Anyone can help?

thanks!

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Custom Variables don't exist any more in analytics.js (aka Universal Analytics). It has been replace with Custom Dimensions and Metrics that are more flexible and powerful.

Advantages of Custom Metrics and dimensions:

- They can be used in filters
- They are first class citizens in the interface, so you will see the custom variable name in the interface (instead of the generic "Custom Variable 5")
- Configured in the interface
- Metrics that are aggregated (not possible with custom vars)
- 20 custom dimensions + 20 custom metrics available, instead of only 5 custom variables

In order to use Custom Dimensions/Metrics, you need to configure them on the interface. Go into admin, drill down into your web property and then there is a tab for "custom definitions".

Then when you track it, you just need to track the value and the id of the custom property eg:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'dimension15':  'My Custom Dimension'
});
```

This will send a pageview with the custom dimension attached to it.

You can also set one on the page that will be applied to any pageviews or events that happened on the page.

```
ga('set', 'dimension5', 'custom data');
```

Note that only setting it won't send to GA, so if you decide to use `set` make sure you call a `send` afterwards at least once on the page to actually send that data to GA.

More Info: [Developer Docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets)

Comment: note: if trying to filter on a custom dimension you must add the filter at the 'View' level (eg. All Website Data) and not the 'Account' level. you'll only see custom dimensions under view

Comment: Here is a link for reference: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/customdimsmets

Comment: Here is the development docs for reference: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets. The last link shared doesn't use Universal Analytics in its examples.

Comment: How do you actually filter/create dimensions out of those data? I can't find my way around this once in the Analytics interface

Comment: Ok found about it. It is in Admin > Custom Definitions > Custom Dimensions ([More Info](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/customdimsmets)). I still find pretty absurd though that you have to call {dimension5: 'my custom Dimension'}  instead of {my_custom_dimension: 'my_custom_value'}.

Comment: Thanks a lot - mostly for the "make sure you send the SEND after the SET" - I had it vice versa and wondered why it didnt work!

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger What do you mean with the absurd part in your comment? Are you saying I can't do this: ga('set', 'userRole', 'Customer');

Comment: No I mean that once in the GA interface, it is hard to filter data over a certain dimension. I would expect to being able to send `{is_subscribed: true}` in the code, and filter page views over the `is_subscribed` dimension, but it isn't easy as it sounds.