# google anlytics new version for setting custom variables

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

this is my new analytics code:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-000000-0', 'mysite.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

I found in the analytics api, that I set a custom var like:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
  1,                   // This custom var is set to slot #1.  Required parameter.
  'Items Removed',     // The name acts as a kind of category for the user activity.  Required parameter.
  'Yes',               // This value of the custom variable.  Required parameter.
  2                    // Sets the scope to session-level.  Optional parameter.
```

]);

but the variable "_gaq" is not defiend, and where do I place this code?
my analytics is just after the  tag

Comment: There are no custom vars in Universal Analytics (and no _gaq variable), google for "custom dimensons" instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set custom variables through the new analytics.js of GA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440499/how-to-set-custom-variables-through-the-new-analytics-js-of-ga)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Universal Analytics doesn't have the .push it has a ga() function.

**Also there are no custom variables in Universal Analytics. In Universal Analytics we get custom dimensions and metrics.**

Your custom variables are pretty much the same as the new custom dimensions.

The main difference is that they are set up in the GA interface instead of via arguments to the old .push function.

ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Yes');

[Set up or edit custom dimensions & metrics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829)

Comment: found it, thanks.  do you know if those filters apply to real time users report?

Comment: Good question im not sure if you can see Custom Dimensions and metrics in the real time reports.  I just checked a few of the sites i have access to and it doesnt apear you have access to custom dimension info from the realitime reports.  Also the realtime api doesnt apear to let you export the info either.