# How to upgrade _setCustomVar to Universal Analytics

Tags: universal-analytics

I have look at the Universal Analytics without finding the correct answer to my problem.

How do I update this line from the old Analytics to the new Universal Analytics?

```
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 1, "splittest", "control", 1]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the Google Universal Analytics will no longer be using custom variables per https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1144414?hl=en. Could you provide a little bit more information on what you're trying to track so a recommendation of which feature you should use can be made?

Comment: Also, have you checked out this SO question and answer on [upgrading GA custom variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440499/how-to-set-custom-variables-through-the-new-analytics-js-of-ga)

Comment: I am using the phpabtest.com splittesting class for Analytics. I am trying to upgrade it for universal analytics.

Comment: If you haven't already tried, I would recommend trying to use the [Custom Dimensions/Metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets) and see if that gives you the same results. Additionally, support for new Google Universal Analytics was [requested over a year ago](https://github.com/briancray/phpA-B/issues/5) and Brian Cray hasn't provided any updates or responses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Custom variables** have been replaced by **custom dimensions** in analytics.js and Universal Analytics:

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'control');
```

You can read more about replacing **custom variables** with **custom dimension** [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/reference/gajs-analyticsjs#custom-vars)